# How to draw link line between two path elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am constructing tree structure diagram with path elements as nodes. The reason I am using path is to create rounded rectangles, all I need is to connect the those paths with line.

I have tried with getBBox(), getTotalLength() and followed too, to get x, y co-ordinates of the path and render the line accordingly, but I didn't get the solution which will solve my problem.

- d3.select('#node1').node().getBBox() is returning width and height of my node as "SVGRect {x: -50, y: -30, width: 100, height: 60}".
- d3.select('#node1').node().getTotalLength() is returning length of the path as "311.42041015625".
- d3.select('#node1').node().getBoundingClientRect() is returning the client position, I could able to get x, y coords butwhen we scroll the screen x, y values are getting changed. Because its taking the coords from the screen I think as far as I gone through.

Here is my "svg" with "path" elements:

```
  <g class="wrapper">

      <path d="M-45,-30h90a5,5 0 0 1 5,5v50a5,5 0 0 1 -5,5h-90a5,5 0 0 1 -5,-5v-50a5,5 0 0 1 5,-5z" id="node1" style="fill: #ffffff; transform: translate(200px, 100px); stroke: #696969; stroke-width: 2;"></path>
      <path d="M-45,-30h90a5,5 0 0 1 5,5v50a5,5 0 0 1 -5,5h-90a5,5 0 0 1 -5,-5v-50a5,5 0 0 1 5,-5z" id="node2" style="fill: #ffffff; transform: translate(400px, 100px); stroke: #696969; stroke-width: 2;"></path>

   </g>
```

Now I should draw line between '#node1' and '#node2' to connect them.
I am new to d3.js, help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Lazy approach: Since your rounded rect paths have solid white fill, you can draw a path between the centres of the rounded rect paths and position it behind the rounded rect paths. In your current case this would be a path between the `translate`values of your rounded rect paths - i.e. a simple path with `.attr('d', 'M200,100L400,100')`.

Comment: @matthias.rocks its working as expected, thankyou for your answer!!!

Comment: good to hear it worked!